# How do I import a .pyd module written in C++ to Python using PyBind11

Tags: python, windows-10, python-3.9, pybind11

I am working on Windows 10 with Python `3.9.7` and have anaconda setup on my laptop.
I have compiled a C++ code `calcSim.cpp` where the module name is `calJaccSimm` and am able to successfully generate a .pyd file with the following extension **.cp39-win_amd64.pyd** as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60699002/how-can-i-build-manually-c-extension-with-mingw-w64-python-and-pybind11) .

I am launching my jupyter notebook at the following location: jupyter-notebook **D:\projects\sem4\code** and my `.pyd` file named calcSim.cp39-win_amd64.pyd is at the same location.

When trying to import module using:

`import calJaccSimm` I am getting `ModuleNotFoundError`.

I have tried the following things:

1. `import sys`

   `sys.path.insert(0, 'D:\projects\sem4\code')`
2. `import os`

   `os.dll_directory("D:\projects\sem4\code")`
3. Setup environment variables with the path '"D:\projects\sem4\code"'
4. Tried putting the generated `.pyd` in different locations like anaconda\DLLs and
   anaconda\lib\site-packages folder.

But after all this, I am still not able to load the module. Please help.

Edit 1: I had multiple versions of python on my machine. I deleted all the versions and re-installed anaconda as well. Still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three places where the module name needs to be consistent: When calling the `PYBIND11_MODULE` macro, in the file name of the extension, and in the import statement inside python.

It seems that your `pyd` file is inconsistently named `calcSim` instead of `calcJaccSimm`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had tried the same thing earlier as well but it did not work then because of multiple python versions issue.